# Firebug show error count icon at Firefox toolbar

Tags: firefox, firebug

Firebug show error count icon at Firefox toolbar (sticker near icon with number). Where exactly can I find full information about thous errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click that icon and switch to the "Console" tab, and you should see them.